# mac bashでのpythonエラーについての質問です

Tags: python

mac 10.11.6 
bash version 4.4.12 
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.|

pythonを勉強中なのですが、ランダムに格言が表示されるプログラムを実行しました。
ファイル名　list-kakugen.py
bashでIDLE 3.6.3を立ち上げて、実行すると正常にランダムに格言が表示されます。

しかし、同じファイルをbashで
pythom3.6 list-kakugen.py 
で実行すると、下記のようなメッセージが出てうまくいきません。何故でしょうか

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list-kakugen.py", line 1, in <module>
    import random
  File "/Users/Yoshi/python3_systemtrade/jissen_python/First-time/random.py", line 11, in <module>
    i = random.randint(0, len(kakugen)-1)
AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'randint'
```

ファイル名　list-kakugen.py

```
import random

kakugen = [
    "能ある鷹は爪を隠す",
    "豚に真珠",
    "二兎を追う者は一兎をも得ず",
    "叩き続けなさい。そうすれば開かれます。"]

i = random.randint(0, len(kakugen)-1)

print( kakugen[i] )
```

Comment: Python初学者がぶつかるありがちな問題ですね。importするモジュール名とプログラムを保存するファイル名がぶつからないように名前をつけましょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/Users/Yoshi/python3_systemtrade/jissen_python/First-time/random.py`

を見に行ってしまっています。

このファイルの名前を変えたりするなどすると、本来あなたが望んでいる`random`を見に行くはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事解決しました。m(__)m